# How to handle time-intervals with timezone in iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to this iOS world, trying to learn how to handle dates and time.

Imagine I have a Class Shop. The shop have time-intervals which represent the open and close time for each day of the week.

Some context data (example string from database, **GMT Timezone**):

```
Monday: "08:00:00-13:00:00, 15:00:00-18:00:00"
Tuesday:"09:00:00-13:00:00, 15:00:00-19:00:00"
Wednesday: "15:00:00-23:59:59"
Thursday: "00:00:00-08:00:00"
etc..
```

Monday for example would have to store 2 time-intervals.

My question is how can I store this data (array of DateIntervals? TimeIntervals? or another more suitable class?) in a Class and get the current time to check if the store is opened or not.

Comment: Are you sure "08:00:00-13:00:00, 15:00:00-18:00:00" is GMT?. It looks like it is local time of the shop. It doesn't look like UTC time. Generally when a date is converted to string to be stored in the server there is a timezone included in the end of string (Z or +0000). In your case just having the time without a date it is probably local time of the shop

Comment: @LeoDabus The local time of the shop is GMT

Comment: First you should use calendar method `dateComponents(in: TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!, from: Date())`. It will return all corresponding date components in GMT timezone

Comment: then create an `enum Weekday: String, CustomStringConvertible` with the weekday names and add a custom initializer that takes an Int from 1-7. initialize it with the weekday component returned by the calendar method and get the weekday description (your dictionary key).

Comment: Then you can get the store hours from your dictionary value with that key. Use a loop to iterate the `components(separatedBy: ", ")` to get the periods and `components(separatedBy: "-")` first and last components to get the the opening and closing times. then all you need is to check if hour and minute components returned from calendar method falls in between the store times

Comment: Try it and if you don't succeed edit your question and add you attempt. I will take a look at it once I get a chance

Answer (score 0):

The native date format for iOS (and Mac OS) is the Date object. A `Date` object represents and instant in time, independent of time zone. You then use a `DateFormatter` to convert a date to a string representation in a particular time zone.

In your case, though, you need to represent timer ranges for days of the week on a variety of different dates.

You should read the `Calendar` class reference in the Xcode documentation. Of particular interest would be the `date(bySetting:value:of:)` method, which will let you start from a given date and calculate a new date by changing the value of various date components.

Comment: Sorry if this is a "dumb" question but how can I convert a String (that don't have a timezone) to a particular timezone? The String may represent UTC, GMT or another timezone.

Comment: You have to know the timezone in which the string is expressed. Otherwise it's meaningless.

Comment: Note that I did not say "convert a string to a timezone." I said "Convert a Date object to a String in a particular timezone." Those are different things.

Comment: Even so, as you wrote "A Date object represents and instant in time, independent of time zone" if you have a Date without a timezone how can you convert it to a String in a particular timezone?

Comment: A Date object represents an instant in time, anywhere on the planet earth. In order to convert that to a date and time string you need to specify a time zone. As I type this, I snap my fingers. The moment of my finger-snap is a `Date`. What time/date is that moment? Depends on your time zone. I'm in the US Eastern time zone, so it is about 16:07 on 11 November. However, if you're in Japan, I snapped my fingers at about 6:07 AM on Sunday 12 November.

Answer (score 0):

You have a set of time intervals for each day. So you need a way to store, for a given day of the week, one or more time intervals. Your time intervals have a start time and an end time. Each of those needs to be represented by an hour, minute, and optionally second.

With that information you can get the current date/time and split it into components. Get the weekday, hour, minute, and second. Using the weekday you can get the appropriate time intervals. Then you can iterate those intervals and see if the current hour, minute, second falls between one of the intervals.

This all assumes that for a given business, your time intervals (open times) are specified in local time for the given business.

When converting the current date/time into its components, you should ensure that you set the calendar's timezone to match the timezone of the business in question.

There is no need for any date comparisons for any of this. You want to compare hours/minutes/seconds of the current date with the hours/minutes/seconds of the open times.